# HTML5 use cache only when offline

Tags: html, caching, offline, cache-manifest

I started to use **HTML5 cache** to view a simple HTML page with one css file and two js files.

My problem is that the cache is used whether I'm offline or not. But I **just want to use the cache when I'm offline**.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

*index.html* file manifest:

```
<html manifest="app.cache">
```

*app.cache* manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/index.html
/css/style.css
/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
/js/functions.min.js
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manifest="app.cache" - not going to solve your problem. It caches all the file listed in manifest file. You have to save your data in local storage or in local db and have to retrieve data from server/local based on connection status [online/offline].

Answer (score 4):

According to [the standard as given at whatwg](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#concept-appcache-mode), this is possible by changing the cache mode from the default `fast` to the `prefer-online` state. There, the instructions given are to add the following at the end of your appcache manifest, after listing all the files you need available offline:

```
SETTINGS:
prefer-online
NETWORK:
*
```

Apparently the idea behind this is to allow adding basic offline support to "legacy" applications that cannot help having to change the html document everytime it is served. I have not verified that this works in any current browser.